# cakephp display data from another controller in pages

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need to display latest article on my apps home page. After reading a lot of questions on stackoverflow, I've tried importing the ArticlesController and using requestAction with no success. Maybe there's a catch that I'm missing, since PagesController doesn't use a model.

What would be the best way to do this?

////////////// edit:

I've got the requestAction working, using following code

**home.ctp view:**

```
$lastarticle = $this->requestAction('/Articles/getarticle');
```

**ArticlesController controller:**

```
public function getarticle() {
    $lastarticle = $this->Article->find('first', array('order' => array('Article.id DESC')));
    return $lastarticle;
}
```

Now, I'd like to know if requestAction is an appropriate way of solving this problem because I've read that it's a waste of resources.

Comment: Can you please post your code, such that we'll get clear idea that what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If your home page just displays articles, why not make your articles/index your home page (it doesn't have to be pages/display/home)? Look into cake routing.

Edit: You can use loadModel or requestAction (post your code for requestAction). Either way, you should cache it for better perfomance http://book.cakephp.org/view/1380/Caching-in-the-Controller

Comment: That's a good thing to know, but I also need to display top 10 products. Articles and products aren't related, so I guess that I'm back to the home view.

Comment: I'm using requestAction (see question edit). Is it better to use caching in the home view, or article controller?